# In WebStorm hide library root and remove colour from the icons and text in sidebar

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, code-editor

Is there a way in WebStorm to to hide the `library root` text next to `node_modules` and change the default colour for the folders which I am pointing in the screenshot below.

[image]